# How to work with Spotify using HTTP requests in Ruby

Tags: ruby, spotify, watir, rest-client

At first I need to make a new playlist in my spotify account then I need to add some songs and then to change order of the songs in playlist. How can I do this using HTTP requests in ruby with Watir or RestClient ?

I already made the script to log me in and to get ACCES TOKEN using RestClient.

```
grant = Base64.encode64("#{CLIENT_ID}:#{CLIENT_SECRET}").delete("\n")

respond = RestClient.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
                       {'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'},
                       {"Authorization" => "Basic #{grant}"})
token_ext =  respond.split(',')
token_ext2 = token_ext[0].split(':')
only_token = token_ext2[1].delete_prefix('"').delete_suffix('"')
puts 'ACCES TOKEN: %s' % [only_token]
```

HTTP Request example from Spotify Docs.
[Add new playlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNyZr.png)

Comment: Please post the specific non-working code you are trying to get working and relevant HTML for the portion of the task you are struggling with.   As it reads right now this question is basically asking the internet to do your homework for you, and that’s not what we do here.

Answer (score 0):

Watir creates HPPT(S) requests via driving a browser.  It is typically used to do automated testing of a web UI.   The example post you gave appears to be a direct call to a web API with a JSON body.  So typically you would use something like REST Client to create such a HTTP request.  Typically this starts with an authentication request to get a token that you then incorporate into the header of subsequent API requests such as the one you linked.    I’d suggest starting with a few basic tutorials for using that gem.

Otherwise to do this with WATIR basically means following the same steps you would manually with a web browser, just with ruby code that uses the watir gem to drive the browser instead of your keyboard and mouse.  That typically starts by navigating to the website, logging in, and then manipulating the UI (fill in input fields, click buttons, etc)